# Slim framework - Call external API

Tags: api, rest, curl, slim

I'm completely new to Slim Framework 2 and I would like to make an HTTP call to an external API.

It would simply something like:
`GET http://website.com/method`

Is there a way to do this using Slim or do I have to use curl for PHP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can build an API using Slim Framework. 
To consume other API, you can use PHP Curl.

So for example:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://website.com/method");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);            // No header in the result 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Return, do not echo result   

// Fetch and return content, save it.
$raw_data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// If the API is JSON, use json_decode.
$data = json_decode($raw_data);
var_dump($data);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll use this if there is no simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  try {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://website.com/method");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE, 2);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    var_dump($data);
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    // do something on exception
  }
?>
```

Comment: please explain a bit

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) which is able to fetch remote files and can be tuned using the [`$context`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) argument. The [fourth example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) shows a get request.

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
```